# How to register DOM id when writing objects dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a problem with this script. At first I had the `<div>`s hard-coded and it was working fine. But then I needed to alter the navigation bar dynamically because I changed the (number of) links.

The problem is that the id's are not registering when they are injected with `element`.innerHTML = (html string).

How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

javascript:

```
 function constructNav() {
   var submenu_layer_innerHTML = "";
   var top_nav_innerHTML = "<UL class=\"nav_category\">";
   for (i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
     submenu_layer_innerHTML = "<div class=\"submenu\" id=\"submenu" + i + "\" onMouseOut=\"timeHideNav('" + i + "','1000')\"> </div>";
     top_nav_innerHTML += "<LI id=\"link" + i + "\"><a href=# onMouseOver=\"expandNav('" + i + "');\">" + links[i] + "</a></LI>";
   }
   top_nav_innerHTML += "</UL>";
   document.getElementById("top_nav").innerHTML = top_nav_innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("submenu_layer").innerHTML = submenu_layer_innerHTML;
 }
```

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var links =["link 1",
    "link 2",
    "link 3",
    "link 4",
    "link 5",
    "link 6"];
</script>

<body onLoad="constructNav();">

<div id="submenu_layer"> </div>
<div id="top_nav"> </div>
```

I'm getting this error in firefox:

```
  line 35: document.getElementById("submenu"+pageNo) is NULL
```

Comment: it works fine in my firefox 11.0, all of the elements have IDs. (link0~ link5, submenu5)

Comment: i get this error in firefox: `document.getElementById("submenu"+pageNo) is NULL`

that started when I changed `<div id="submenu1"></div>` (10 of those) to 6 of those dynamically generated in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `submenu_layer_innerHTML` during each iteration of the `for` loop.  Make sure to use `+=`.

Comment: lool i can't believe that was it  :/. feel like an idiot now. in my defence i'm not using an IDE so its not that easy to spot. thanks though.

Comment: I don't know how much an IDE would help when you don't have any errors.  But still, use an IDE!  [Here's a free one](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express).

Comment: oh because the IDE would have colour-coded the code for me and kept it nicely indented - so I would have spotted my mistake much faster. Thanks, I already have an IDE installed but I never use it. (I'm always making small websites so I just hard-code in notepad)

Answer (score 1):

try jQuery live function ..

```
$("div.something").live('click', function(){ 
  // do something...
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it actually works but i was overriding the innerHTML by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> constructNav is not defined
>   Try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/5GjNs/

Comment: `constructNav()` is defined. I changed the order though, so that `links` is before the `scripts.js` import, so that `links` is defined before the scripts are run.